# Looking for author of Canadian 1980 sci-fi time-travel novel called "Replay" - not the book by Ken Grimwood

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid, I read a great short sci-fi novel that I took out of the Don Mills Public Library in Toronto. I'm pretty sure it was published in 1980 (or perhaps 1979), and it was called "Replay".

I know there's a 1986 book about time travel called "Replay" by Ken Grimwood, and it has a similar story, but it's a different author.

In the Canadian one, a failure of a man in 1990 sees some kind of anomaly, touches it, and goes back to 1980 (when the book came out). He uses his knowledge of the future to get rich by 'inventing' the gadgets of the future, like roads with magnetic disks so cars can drive automatically, flat-panel 3D displays, and hydrogen cells for the self-driving cars. He also uses his knowledge of future marketing and ad campaigns to promote his business. But of course, there are a few catches along the way... Pretty nifty predictions, even though the author was about 40 years early.

I've tried searching on Amazon and eBay, but with no luck. I remember the cover had a drawing of a man's split down the middle, with one side colored red and the other green. Aside from that, no clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Replay&type=Fiction+Titles

Answer (score 8):

This may be a bit late, but I believe the novel in question is *[Rerun](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rerun-novel-Neil-Crichton/dp/0773771301)* by Neil Crichton.

Publisher: PaperJacks Ltd.; 1st thus edition (1977)

From his [own website](http://neilcrichton.webs.com/aboutme.htm):

> *Neil Crichton was born in Calgary, Alberta, Canada, and at one time or another, he lived in Halifax, St. John, Toronto, Regina, and
>   Edmonton. He now lives in Claresholm, Alberta about l30 km. south of
>   Calgary, enjoying a quiet life in a small town.   Trained as a
>   photographer, Neil began writing many years ago. His first project was
>   a science-fiction novel, Rerun, published in both hardcover and
>   paperback. Rerun sold well throughout Canada. See Blog page for
>   reviews of Rerun.*

I first read *Rerun* when it was released and it managed to stay in my library for nearly 30 years and umpteen moves. Sadly, I think it didn't make the last one.

If you can find it, it's a good read.

[image: Cover]

Comment: What about this novel matches the description?

Comment: @JonathanCohen Glad you found the story you were looking for! Please remember to **accept** this answer (click the checkmark on the left) in order to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is a real Hail Mary longshot. But, doing some searching I found a Canadian book published in 1975 called Replay by a Don Bailey. It appears it may be a collection of short stories rather than a full novel. But, it is possible that one of the stories could be of novella length. Unfortunately I cannot find a review/summary of the contents and cannot find a cover picture so I can't match any of the points you described. But, I thought it might be worth a shot.

More description of the book information can be found below.

Good luck.

Replay : 
stories / 
Don Bailey
 1975 
English Book Book  : Fiction 149 pages ; 22 cm

[Ottawa] : Oberon Press, ; ISBN: 0887501729 9780887501722 0887501737 9780887501739

Author(s): Bailey, Don.
Publication: [Ottawa] : Oberon Press, 
Year: 1975 
Description: 149 pages ; 22 cm 
Language: English 
Standard No: ISBN: 0887501729; 9780887501722; 0887501737 ((pbk.)); 9780887501739 ((pbk.)); National Library: 000170947 LCCN: 76-351009
 SUBJECT(S)
Descriptor: Manners and customs.
Genre/Form: Fiction.
Geographic: Canada -- Social life and customs -- Fiction. 
Canada.
Class Descriptors: LC: PZ4.B1513; PR9199.3.B34; PS8553A43; Dewey: 813/.5/4; NLC: PS8553* 
Responsibility: by Don Bailey. 
Vendor Info: Baker and Taylor (BTCP) 
Material Type: Fiction (fic) 
Document Type: Book 
Entry: 19760202 
Update: 20160401 
Accession No: OCLC: 2035322 
Database: WorldCat

Comment: Possible but unlikely.  Bailey was a novelist, poet, and screenwriter.  I think his only science fiction-esque foray was in writing an episode for a horror radio series on the CBC.  I think his *Replay* was only ever printed once, with just one cover that doesn't match the OP's description: https://www.amazon.ca/Replay-Stories-Don-Bailey/dp/0887501737  But I might be wrong (and thanks for trying regardless).

Comment: Agreed. It is waaay out there as a possibility. As you correctly pointed out, it is so obscure it doesn't even have a real book cover assigned. I.e. if you look very closely at the lower right corner it says: "Note: this is not the actual book cover." Looking at all the instances of the book for sale I could find, I think they have the same generic cover listed.